# Get another element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

I build multi level menu and my HTML structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 <li>
   <ul> #this is set up as display: none;
     <li>subitem 1</li>
     <li>subitem 2</li>
     <li>subitem 3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>item 3</li>
 <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And I am solving a question, how to display all subitems after moving the cursor on the **item1**.
I can do something like this:

```
   $('ul li ul').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).find('li').show();
   });
```

But this doesn't works me... could anyone help me, please, how to display sub-ul block of items for mouseover event?

Thank you

**EDIT:** Thanks for your replies guys, I already found my stupid fault thanks to your helps.

Comment: It's not clear if you're saying the `ul` is `display: none`, or if the children of that `ul` are `display: none`, which could make a difference. But if all of the `li`'s in a list are not shown, I'm not sure the parent `ul` will be available to `mouseover`.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/kSq4T/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach it to the parent `LI`, otherwise there is not an element that is displayed for the `mouseover` to fire on.

Note as well that if all you have in the `LI` containing the `UL` is the [`UL` with the non-displayed `LI`'s](http://jsfiddle.net/kSq4T/2/), it will potentially be hard to `mouseover` that as well.

```
$('ul li ul').parent().mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('li').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kSq4T/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could always add a class to your item elements and do something like this:

```
       <ul>
 <li class="item">item 1</li>
 <li class="item">item 2</li>
 <li>
   <ul> #this is set up as display: none;
     <li>subitem 1</li>
     <li>subitem 2</li>
     <li>subitem 3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>item 3</li>
 <li>item 4</li>
</ul>

$('#item').mouseover(function()
      $(this).children.show();
```

Comment: You do mean `.children()` right? And `$('.item')`? Are you sure this is all the OP needs to do to resolve the issue?

Comment: This should work if you put it in (document).ready().  Alternatively you could add an onclick event to your li tag like this:  <li onclick="showChildren()">  then write your javascript function showChildren(element){element.children.show();}

Comment: You need to read your answer a bit more carefully. The `item` class attributes you have on the `LI`'s do not have `UL` children, your jQuery selector is looking for an `id="item"` element, not classes as your markup indicates, your jQuery code is missing some fundamental parts (such as, curly braces on the anonymous function and a closing parenthetical), and your `children` should be `children()`. So I don't think your answer could work without significant improvement. `:)`

Comment: And if jQuery is available, inline click handler's should be avoided.

Comment: I agree just putting possibilities out there.  And sorry for the formatting/syntax errors.  Still pretty new to the site so typing code in these little boxes is a little foreign to me.  Maybe I'll cut and paste from an editor right from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

write your function in `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('ul > li > ul').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).find('li').show();
   });

});
```